# I want to display images in my views in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a blogging application with Laravel and so I got this in my view

```
<img src="{{$post->image}}" />
```

the image is not showing up but the post title shows up.
I tried:

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

and its return:

```
The "public/storage" directory already exists.
```

but yet still no image displays

Comment: how do you store the image?

Comment: in my Laravel package i have this folder public/storage/posts which contains the images which i have uploaded and there is also also another folder  storage /app/public/posts that also contain the images too

Comment: can you give an example of `$post->image`?

Comment: $post->image is meant to display images of each post created

Comment: can you give the example content of it? example `/storage/posts/img.png` or `/posts/img.png` or what else?

Comment: Is your `public/storage` folder an actual directory or a symbolic link? The former may explain why your use of the artisan command didn't work.

Comment: I think your problem is the image URL/content is not found. show me the content of your posts table

Comment: //uplaod the image to the storage

        $image = $request->image ->store('posts');
        //create post
        post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request -> description,
            'content' => $request -> content,
            'image'=> $image

Comment: here is the content of my post table :   Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: you need to try print `{{$post}}` to check is the value of attribute image empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you upload the image to a private storage folder so it's will never show. You should upload to the public folder using code like this:

```
$image = $request->image->store('posts','public');
```

then if you want to show it just use `<img src="{{url("storage/".$post->image)}}" />`